# Como fazer background que se repete com sprites?

Tags: css, spritesheet

Eu estava criando um botão com `background:` feito com um `sprite`, porém, ele fica todo errado, eu quero que ele fique igual a este:

[image: Botão Normal] [image: Botão com :hover]

Só que ele está todo bugado, assim:

[image: Botão Bugado]

Meu CSS:

```
.botao {    
    background:url(http://testetabela.esy.es/botoes.png) 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 transparent;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 transparent;
    position:relative;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    z-index:0;
}
.botao:hover {
    background:url(http://testetabela.esy.es/botoes.png) -8px 0;
}
```

**[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/59YSK/)**

Gostaria de deixá-lo como nas duas primeiras imagens, a 1ª é o botão normal, a 2ª é o botão com `:hover`.

Comment: Alexandre, considere colocar seu código no http://www.jsfiddle.net/, está complicado te ajudar apenas com estas imagens.

Comment: Amigo a cima tem um link EXEMPLO. Leia minha pergunta e procure o nome Exemplo com um link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/59YSK/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu usaria gradientes por CSS como o @Sergio e o @PauloMaciel sugeriram. Mas se você quer mesmo usar imagens, elas precisam estar empilhadas na sua *spritesheet*, que pode ter 2px por 100px:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí é só deslocar a imagem no eixo Y no `:hover`:

```
.botao:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yn8/)

Comment: Obrigado, isso mesmo que queria! Vlw!!!

Answer (score 4):

O problema aqui é que você está a usar uma imagem que por sí já tem esse efeito zebra. Para usar imagens de fundo dessa maneira, que no fundo são tiras pequenas que se repetem na horizontal, então a imagem não pode ter nada de branco.

Para usar sprites então a sua imagem original tem de ter as duas imagens inteiras, não vejo como ter duas tiras/linhas com espaço entre elas na mesma imagem e fazer repeat só da parte que procura. Então aí teriam de estar como o @bfavareto sugere, uma em cima da outra.

Uma imagem/sprite com o botão completo seria assim (imagem/ficheiro único):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no CSS:

```
background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi14e.jpg');
background-position:-5px 0px;
```

e para a outra parte da imagem

```
background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi14e.jpg');
background-position:-115px 0px;
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/q99dR/)

---

Pode também usar somente CSS, pode por exemplo usar [**esta ferramenta**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/#) para escolher cores e ao clicar pode ver o CSS.

Somente com CSS a sua imagem vai precisar de:

> **gradient:** para ter cor diferente no topo e no fundo
>   **border-radius:** para fazer os cantos redondos

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/J2wNU/)

```
.botao {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #000000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777), to(#000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777, #000000);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #777, #000000);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #777, #000000);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #777, #000000);
    padding: 13px 26px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0 1px 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.botao:hover {
    border-top-color: #28597a;
    background: #0422ba;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#27274f), to(#0422ba));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #27274f, #0422ba);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #27274f, #0422ba);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #27274f, #0422ba);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #27274f, #0422ba);
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Não, eu não quero gradient, eu quero somente com meu sprite, ele está em PNG!!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, mas o seu sprite não tem cor escura, só azul e branco.

Comment: Eu já estou fazendo com imagem porque gradient não funciona no internet explorer! Antes estava com duas imagens, só que eu quis juntar e criar um sprite.

Comment: Esta imagem que está lá: http://testetabela.esy.es/botoes.png

Comment: Nesse sprite: http://testetabela.esy.es/botoes.png possui duas listras preto e azul, cada uma com 2px de largura.

Comment: Eu usei a ferramenta http://www.spritecow.com/ para pegar o código do sprite. Me ajuda ai cara!!! :/

Comment: @AlexandreLopes fiz um update da minha resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, de coração, vlw mesmo, mais o bfavaretto fez como eu queria, mais obrigado pela força, você tem me ajudado muito ultimamente.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes não tem problema. Eu acho tambem que a resposta do bfavareto é melhor e votei nela também :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando apenas css:

**CSS**

```
.botao {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3f3f40, #161617); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */   
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#3f3f40, #161617); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3f3f40, #161617); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#3f3f40, #161617); /* Standard syntax */
    border-radius:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;      
    position:relative;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    z-index:0;
}
.botao:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#164fda, #121fa0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */   
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#164fda, #121fa0); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#164fda, #121fa0); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#164fda, #121fa0); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Veja no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59YSK/3/)